# I port forwarded to my local apache server, but it does not work

Tags: apache-http-server, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I am new to the server running.

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4 and set up from my Mac. So, I connected via ssh, and set up a file server on my local network. But I want to access my files from anywhere.

I installed apache server, when I enter with the 192.168.1.108 IP address, everything is fine and working. But when I use my external IP it does not. What should be the problem?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question; however, this would be a risky setup. It’s worth looking into setting up a VPN for this.

Comment: Depends on where you use your external IP, it could be just that you are ["hairpinning"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) and your router does not / was not configured to support it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are not forwording the ssh port of your router to your raspberry pi (Check your firewall settings of the router as well).
But keep in mind it's **dangerous** to forward such ports directly to an network device in your LAN.

Like mentioned in the comments before have a look at the topic VPN or at least forward a "non default port" of your router to your ssh port of the raspberry pi.

A recommendation off topic:
if you havn't already done this check out the topic Dyndns as well because your routers IP can dynamicly change.

Comment: I have checked Dyndns before, and heard about the firewall settings. When I shut down my firewall, canyouseeme.org tells me that "fail reason: Connection timed out". I do not know why. Before shutting down the firewall, it said "fail reason: Server not reachable"

Comment: Disable your firewall once again and do a port scan of your IP e.g. with https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap to verify your port is open. If this is the case your forwarding doesn’t work properly probably. Did you configure a static IP on your raspberry pi? (not in DHCP range as well)

Comment: Yes, my raspberry has a static IP on my local network. I scanned my ports, the website tells me that I have 0 open ports.

Comment: Okay, can you post images of your settings?

Comment: https://ibb.co/nwqxS2r Here you go. What other settings should I post? Also I can access these ports via local IPs.

Comment: Please post your Apache settings as well. (You could edit your question to insert the image)